# Theoretical Justification Behind the Mean of a Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics

In school, we always learned that:

- If $X$ is a random variable with a probability distribution of $f_X(x)$, then the mean of $x$ (i.e. expected value) is the integral $\int x f_X(x)\, dx$

This works out such that the average value of $X$ will correspond to this integral.

I have always accepted this fact at face value and never really tried to understand it beyond this point. This brings me to my question:

**Is there a proof that shows why the average value of a random variable "x" is given by this integral? Or is this simply by definition?**

Thanks!

Comment: "...the most probable value of $x$..." No, that's called the mode.

Comment: sorry - translation/language

Comment: Now with that fixed - you can't prove a definition. Motivate, yes, but prove, no. It is just an extension of the case for a discrete random variable.

Comment: @ Sean: Thank you! I would be curious to hear your motivation!

Answer (score 3):

It's simply by definition.

If you have studied some mechanics, you might notice that it is similar to finding the centre of mass of some object when given a density function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some intuition that works well when the random variable is discrete. Let's assume that $X$ is a random variable that takes values in $1,2,3,\dots, n$ with respective probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$.

What does it mean when we say $P(X=1) = p_1$? The frequentist notion of probability simply states that if we have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N$ equal in distribution to $X$ where $N$ is very large, then
$$f^N_1:=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{I}_{X_i=1} \approx P(X_1=1)=P(X=1).$$

That is, $p_k$ tells us (with high probability) the approximate proportion of random variables in $X_1,\dots,X_N$ that will be equal to $k$, which we denote by $f^N_k$.

So, the expected value of $X$ then tells us,

$$E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^n kp_k \approx \sum_{k=1}^n kf^N_k = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{I}_{X_i=k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^n k\mathbb{I}_{X_i=k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i.$$

The argument above isn't quite rigorous, and it's even a little circular (we use the law of large numbers for indicator functions to imply the law of large numbers for discrete random variables), but I think it gives a good sense of why the expectation operator is defined the way it is.

If $X$ is discrete but infinite state, the argument is almost exactly the same. In the continuous case, we can now suppose $X$ has pdf $f$. Then we can approximate $X$ by the discrete random variable,
$$X^n := \frac{\lfloor nX\rfloor}{n}.$$

Then the expected value of $X^n$ is,
$$E[X^n] = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{z}{n}\int_{\frac{z}{n}}^{\frac{z+1}{n}} f(y)\,dy.$$
This is essentially a Riemann sum that converges to $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} yf(y)\,dy$$
as desired.

Edit: Had a typo in my definition of $X^n$.

Edit 2: My argument above is non-rigorous. However, if you want a rigorous proof, the law of large numbers states exactly that the standard definition of expected value is equivalent to the notion of a long-term average. You can look up any proof of the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> This works out such that the average value of $X$ will correspond to this integral.

Not exactly. There two different things here. One is the mean (or **expected value**) of a random variable. This can be computed as an integral, if the random variable is continuous (and well behaved), so that its probability law can be described by a density function $f_X(x)$

$$\mu = E[X]= \int f_X(x) dx $$

(If instead the random variable is discrete, the mean is computed as $E[X]= \sum_x x p(x)$ )

Secondly, there is the **average** (arithmetic mean, or sample mean) of a set of $n$ results of a experiment, which are regarded as "realizations" of a random variable $X$ (or, equivalently, as $n$ random variables, independent and identically distributed).

$$\bar X = \frac{\sum X_i}{n}$$

Notice a crucial difference: $\mu$ is a fixed number, while $\bar X$ is itself a random variable (takes different values in different experiments).

Your quoted assertion, actually says that *in some sense* $\bar X$ tends to $\mu$: if $n$ is large, almost always (under certain restrictions) the values will be be similar.

This is not always true, though. To learn about the restrictions, the precise meaning and the proof of this property, you need to read about the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

To get a general feeling of why this might be true, see forgottenarrow's answer.